# LogShipping frequency for backup/copy/restore

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I wish to create a LogShipping job that runs every 5 minutes. What is the best way to do this so that the backup/copy/restore does not collide?

Maybe Sql server knows how to handle this, but I was concerned if I put 5 mins into all of the scheduled times, that I would get some sort of conflict.

i.e. would this create a problem?

- Primary server: starts backup at 9am
- Secondary server: starts copy at 9am
- Secondary server: starts restore at 9am

Would staggering them be a better idea?

- Primary server: starts backup at 9:00am
- Secondary server: starts copy at 9:01am
- Secondary server: starts restore at 9:02am

The database is only approx 200mb in backup size and the two sql servers are running on the same local network.

Comment: Just wondering... Have you considered mirroring as a HADR solution? I've found log shipping to be a bit, well, *meh*.

Comment: Thanks gbn, I am actually investigating it at the moment because of the issues with the above and also some difficulties around the disconnecting of connections using the secondary server (When I dont disconnect them, it keeps failing the job ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At work, we do log shipping with a 100 GB database.
We do everything (backup, ship, restore) only every 15 minutes (not 5), and we do it like this:

- Primary server: starts backup at 9am
- Secondary server: starts copy at 9am
- Secondary server: starts restore at 9am

We never experienced any concurrency problems doing this, and we're doing this for about 5 years now. SQL Server is able to handle this alone, it just avoids collision by "delaying" until the next schedule.

For example, if you just leave everything scheduled at 9 am, SQL Server will do this:

- 9 am:

  - primary server starts backup A
- 9.05 am:

  - primary server starts backup B
  - secondary server copies backup A
- 9.10 am:

  - primary server starts backup C
  - secondary server copies backup B
  - secondary server restores backup A

And so on...

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is great to know even though I wont be using log shipping this time round.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really solve the above problem, but I ended up using Transaction Replication and I didn't need to worry about the above complicated timing issues.